# What happens when GET robots.txt returns an unrelated html file?

Tags: robots.txt, google-crawlers

I have a web server capable of serving the assets of various web apps. When a requested asset doesn't exist, it sends back index.html. In other words:

- GET /img/exists.png -> exists.png
- GET /img/inexistent.png -> index.html

This also means that:

GET /robots.txt -> index.html

How will google (and other) crawlers handle this? Will they detect that robots.txt is invalid and ignore it (same as returning 404)? Or will they penalize my ranking for serving an invalid robots.txt? Is this acceptible, or should I make a point of returning 404 when the app I'm serving has no robots.txt?

Comment: Why doesn't it return status 404 when the resource doesn't exist? Is this a choice on your part, or are you stuck with this for reasons beyond your control?

Comment: @plasticinsect Originally, it was to support being a single-page app. So anything apart from assets could potentially be a path to a section of the app. If you request /home, it serves index.html and shows the home view. If you request /about, it serves index.html and shows the about view. We don't want to make an exhaustive list of routes because it's actually a generalized server capable of serving any app... (as always, the stackoverflow version of the problem is simplified) We're working on a better pattern for this, but for now this is what we have and it has to work...

Answer (score 2):

Every robots.txt handler that I know of deals with invalid lines by simply discarding them. So an HTML file (which presumably does not contain any valid robots.txt directives) would be effectively treated as if it were a blank file. This is not really part of any official standards, though. The [(semi-)official standard](http://www.robotstxt.org/norobots-rfc.txt) assumes that any robots.txt file will contain robot.txt directives. Behavior for a robots.txt file that contains HTML is undefined.

If you care about crawlers, your bigger problem is not that you serve an invalid robot.txt file, it's that you have no mechanism to tell crawlers (or anyone else) when a resource does not exist. From the crawlers point of view, your site will contain some normal pages plus an infinite number of exact copies of the home page. I strongly encourage you to find a way change your setup so resources that don't exist return status 404.